# Декоратор для запроса токена

Tags: python, aiohttp

Пишу REST API.
Я делаю запросы get и delete, и оба они должны быть выполнены только в том случае, если присутствует токен в headers.
Я делаю в каждом запросе проверку на наличие токена, но мне хочется сделать так, чтобы код не повторялся. Я думал добавить к каждой функции декоратор, но у меня не вышло. Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

```
import json
import asyncio
import asyncpg
from aiohttp import web


class User(web.View):
    def __init__(self, request):
        super().__init__(request)
        self.pool = self.request.app['pool']

    async def get(self):
        # ВОТ КОД, ГДЕ ОН ИСПОЛЬЗУЕТСЯ ВПЕРВЫЕ
        token = None

        if 'x-api-key' in self.request.headers:
            token = self.request.headers['x-api-key']

        if not token:
            response_obj = {
                'message': 'Токен отсутсвует'
            }
            return web.Response(status=401, body=json.dumps(response_obj))
       # КОНЕЦ

        try:
            async with self.pool.acquire() as connection:
                user = await connection.fetchrow("SELECT * from users WHERE api_key = '{}';".format(token))
                current_user = dict(user)
                user_data = {
                    'id': current_user['id'],
                    'email': current_user['email'],
                    'first_name': current_user['first_name'],
                    'last_name': current_user['last_name'],
                    # 'created': current_user['created'],
                    'is_active': current_user['is_active'],
                    # 'api_key': current_user['api_key']
                }
                return web.Response(body=json.dumps(user_data))
        except Exception as e:
            response_obj = {'message': str(e)}
            return web.Response(status=500, body=json.dumps(response_obj))

    async def delete(self):
        # ВОТ, ГДЕ ОН ИСПОЛЬЗУЕТСЯ ВТОРОЙ РАЗ
        token = None

        if 'x-api-key' in self.request.headers:
            token = self.request.headers['x-api-key']

        if not token:
            response_obj = {
                'message': 'Токен отсутсвует'
            }
            return web.Response(status=401, body=json.dumps(response_obj))
        # КОНЕЦ

        try:
            async with self.pool.acquire() as connection:
                await connection.execute("UPDATE users SET is_active = FALSE WHERE api_key = '{}';".format(token))
                response_obj = {
                    'message': 'Пользователь удалён'
                }
                return web.Response(body=json.dumps(response_obj))
        except Exception as e:
            response_obj = {'message': str(e)}
            return web.Response(status=500, body=json.dumps(response_obj))
```

Comment: а где у Вас в коде декоратор?

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
import asyncio
import asyncpg
from aiohttp import web


def get_token(func):
    def wrap(self):
        token = None

        if 'x-api-key' in self.request.headers:
            token = self.request.headers['x-api-key']

        if token:
            try:
                return func(self, token)
            except Exception as e:
                response_obj = {'message': str(e)}
                return web.Response(status=500, body=json.dumps(response_obj))
        else:
            response_obj = {
                'message': 'Токен отсутсвует'
            }
            return web.Response(status=401, body=json.dumps(response_obj))

    return wrap


class User(web.View):
    def __init__(self, request):
        super().__init__(request)
        self.pool = self.request.app['pool']

    @get_token
    async def get(self, token):
        async with self.pool.acquire() as connection:
            user = await connection.fetchrow("SELECT * from users WHERE api_key = '{}';".format(token))
            current_user = dict(user)
            user_data = {
                'id': current_user['id'],
                'email': current_user['email'],
                'first_name': current_user['first_name'],
                'last_name': current_user['last_name'],
                # 'created': current_user['created'],
                'is_active': current_user['is_active'],
                # 'api_key': current_user['api_key']
            }
            return web.Response(body=json.dumps(user_data))

    @get_token
    async def delete(self, token):
        async with self.pool.acquire() as connection:
            await connection.execute("UPDATE users SET is_active = FALSE WHERE api_key = '{}';".format(token))
            response_obj = {
                'message': 'Пользователь удалён'
            }
            return web.Response(body=json.dumps(response_obj))
```